# In an arm32 image-based container, readdir returns EOVERFLOW when directory is empty

Tags: c, linux, docker, arm

Upon calling readdir function in a C program within an arm32-based container executing on x64-based Ubuntu 19.10 host, the call returns EOVERFLOW for empty directories (e.g., /mnt, /media) instead of returning 0.

Have others observed this issue?  Is this a configuration issue?  If so, how can it be fixed?

Versions:

- Guest: debian:buster- backports@sha256:8f27850df2144df1598b5c76b213616ecaab08e804a6d84ddace1455d8cbd9f0
- Host: Ubuntu 19.10, amd64, Docker version: 19.03.6-0ubuntu1~19.10.1
- Qemu version: 1:4.0+dfsg-0ubuntu9.6

Repro steps:

- Build an image named crystal-for-buster-armhf:v1 based on Debian Buster for arm32 using the Dockerfile and build.sh script available [here](https://github.com/rvprasad/docker-files/tree/master/crystal-for-buster-armhf).
- Start a container based on this image.
- Compile and build the below program.
- Execute the resulting executable with a directory name as a command line argument.

```c
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#undef _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *entry;

  if ((dir = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
    perror("opendir() error");
  else {
    puts("contents:");
    while (1) {
      errno = 0;
      entry = readdir(dir);
      if (entry == NULL) {
        printf("Errno: %d   EOVERFLOW: %d\n", errno, EOVERFLOW);
        break;
      }
      printf("  %s\n", entry->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dir);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Your code prints `EOVERFLOW` because you do that whenever `entry` is `NULL`, but in all cases I see that `errno` is actually 0. You don't appear to ever be checking `errno`.

Comment: He prints out `errno`.

Comment: Yes, I said that. It's always 0.

Comment: No, he said that `errno` is `EOVERFLOW` instead of 0.

Comment: I have read your entire comment.

Comment: @larsks I printed values of both `errno` and `EOVERFLOW` to help check set error number.  I am not checking `errno` cos' when entry is NULL is both the successful (all entries read) and erroneous termination condition for `readdir`.  That said, I am curious about the difference in your set up that did not lead to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using glibc (most Linux-based systems), you need to compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`. The default is still 32-bit `off_t`, and with it 32-bit `ino_t`, and in such a configuration, `readdir`, `stat`, etc. will fail with `EOVERFLOW` if the inode number does not fit in 32 bits. Many modern filesystems always have inode numbers that don't fit in 32 bits.